# Laravel 6.x - Cannot use session() global helper on public folder

Tags: php, laravel, session, global, helper

I'm working on a custom login controller that saves some query results on session using the global helper session() and then redirects to a page in the public folder to retrieve the session data, validate and display info.

I can set the variables using session()->put() succesfully and print them on the same controller (for testing purposes), but when I try to retrieve them on the public page it returns me the error "Call to undefined function session()".

I'm setting the variables like this, inside a controller where I also do a query to verify if username and password exist on the database.

```php
session()->put(['usrNom'=>$checkLogin[0]->Nombre,
                'usrPer'=>$perArray,
                'usrEmail'=>$checkLogin[0]->Email,
                'usrCve'=>$checkLogin[0]->ClaveEmpleado]);
```

I can print them successfully with their expected values on the same controller

```php
print_r(session()->get('usrPer'));
print_r(session()->get('usrNom'));
```

Or it redirects to my public page

```
return Redirect::to('/modulos/dashboard');
```

In the index.php on the /modulos/dashboard public folder I have:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Session;

$usrNom = session()->get('usrNom');
$usrPer = session()->get('usrPer');
echo "usr ".$usrNom;
```

However, instead of printing the values I get the error message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function session() in C:\Users\Lucania\Documents\Proyects\was\public\modulos\dashboard\index.php Stack trace: #0 {main}
```

The path is symlinked to the xampp/htdocs folders, is properly working and accesible via http://localhost/was/ instead of using php artisan serv

How can I make it work? I'm pretty new to Laravel, so I'm sure it's something I'm overlooking. Thanks for yout time.

Comment: can you share your all index.php ?

Comment: Hi, I just omitted the "<?php" in the index.php on the modulos/dashboard/ folder.  For now, what I posted here is everything it has. Or maybe you need the full controller code?